# Is there a way to prevent emails sent using javamail from being forwarded automatically?

Tags: jakarta-mail

When emails sent through javamail are automatically forwarded to invalid email addresses the smtp service counts them as bounces against our performance even though the original email was delivered.  Is there a way in javamail to prevent auto forwarding of the email?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you are doing, from where you send which emails to what, where bounce emails are generated and how they affect your performance. Also add the relevant source code you have and the configuration of your mail server.

Comment: You could try setting  [mail.smtp.from](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) to direct the bounces or set the [2.1.55.  Header Field: Sensitivity](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4021#section-2.1.55) to try to control the forwarding.